# Check if a customer already made a purchase in Journey Builder decision split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, webservices

All the new leads that enter the journey receive an e-mail. If they haven't made a purchase in the following 7 days they receive a different e-mail. So my logic is checking if the Service Cloud AccountID also exists in the Service Cloud orders.

The table names are Account_Salesforce and Order_Salesforce. The tables are related through the respective variables ID and AccountID.

Can this be done through a decision split? Will it work if I say ID is equal to AccountID? Will it automatically loop through all orders?